# Notion of absolute continuity of an orthogonal stochastic measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I attempted to [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68936/why-cram%c3%a9r-spectral-representation-and-not-dtft-for-stochastic-process/69093#69093) a [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68936) on dsp.stackexchange about the Cramér representation of wide-sense stationary discrete-time stochastic processes, and I failed to find any references that discuss the notion of absolute continuity of an orthogonal stochastic measure on $[0,2\pi)$ with respect to Lebesgue measure. I didn't even find anything that suggested an *analogue* of the Radon-Nikodym derivative for an orthogonal stochastic measure.

I took courses in measure-theoretic probability long ago, and I accept that there could very easily be an obvious answer that I fail to see.

- Is there an analogue of the Radon-Nikodym derivative for an orthogonal stochastic measure with respect to Lebesgue measure?
- If not, is there a way to explain *why* to someone in my situation?

Comment: I thought I had an answer when a search led me to the [**Radon-Nikodym property**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property) of Hilbert spaces. I hoped to use the fact that an orthogonal stochastic measure takes values in a Hilbert space, but I convinced myself that an orthogonal stochastic measure does *not* have bounded variation, so the result does not guarantee a Radon-Nikodym derivative for such a measure.